# What is the reason behind Gazwa-E-Hind?

Tags: jihad, war, battles, hindu

As per my understanding, Gazwa-E-Hind is the prophecy that one day war will be brought upon the Indian subcontinent to invade these lands. Two groups will lead this war on the Indian subcontinent.

But my question is, why will there be a need for this? Why bring war? What's the background behind this hadith? Why only the Indian subcontinent and not any other land mass? Please clarify.

Comment: i am not sure if that hadith specifically about Hind is Sahih. but anyway there is a concept called "offensive Jihad" in islam. when the Muslims are capable, it is fardh to go out and give an ultimatum of "convert, become dhimmah, or war" to all kuffar, in general. See the verse [9/29](https://quranx.com/9.29) and the story of why [Umar RA invaded persia](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3159)

Answer (score 2):

There is no unique reason for the conquest of Hind. Islam prescribes conquest of essentially *every* place to bring it under Islamic rule. Commands to fight war such as [9:29](https://quran.com/9/29?translations=20), [9:36](https://quran.com/9/36?translations=20), [9:73](https://quran.com/9/73?translations=20), [9:123](https://quran.com/9/123?translations=20) etc. are all generic in wording, not specific to any named land.

The reason behind all conquests in Islam is to achieve the [superiority](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2810) and imposition of Islam, either as the religion of the people, or as the authority and law to which people are made subservient.

> قاتلوا الذين لا يؤمنون ... حتى يعطوا الجزية عن يد وهم صاغرون
>
> Fight those who do not believe ... until they give the jizyah willingly while they are humbled.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 9:29](https://quran.com/9/29?translations=20)</sup>

> أمرت أن أقاتل الناس حتى يشهدوا أن لا إله إلا الله وأن محمدا رسول الله، ويقيموا الصلاة، ويؤتوا الزكاة، فإذا فعلوا ذلك عصموا مني دماءهم وأموالهم إلا بحق الإسلام، وحسابهم على الله
>
> I have been ordered (by Allah) to fight against the people until they testify that none has the right to be worshiped but Allah and that Muhammad is Allah's Messenger (ﷺ), and offer the prayers perfectly and give the obligatory charity, so if they perform that, then they save their lives and property from me except for Islamic laws and then their reckoning (accounts) will be done by Allah.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:25)</sup>

And the Hikmah behind it according to various scholars is that it serves various interests such as removing obstacles to conversion to Islam by the conquered populace, facilitating their conversion by impressing them with Islamic rule. And it also removes threats to the safety of the Muslims by strengthening them and removing their opponents from power.

Further, for example there are prophecies of the conquest of the lands of Arabia, Persia, Rome, Constantinople etc. Hind is by no means the only place whose conquest is explicitly mentioned.

> ‏ تغزون جزيرة العرب فيفتحها الله ثم فارس فيفتحها الله ثم تغزون الروم فيفتحها الله
>
> You will attack Arabia and Allah will enable you to conquer it, then you would attack Persia and He would make you to conquer it. Then you would attack Rome and Allah will enable you to conquer it.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2900)</sup>

> أول جيش من أمتي يغزون مدينة قيصر مغفور لهم
>
> The first army amongst my followers who will invade Caesar's City will be forgiven their sins.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2924)</sup>

> إن الله زوى لي الأرض فرأيت مشارقها ومغاربها وإن أمتي سيبلغ ملكها ما زوي لي منها
>
> Allah drew the ends of the world near one another for my sake. And I have seen its eastern and western ends. And the dominion of my Ummah would reach those ends which have been drawn near me (to see)
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2889a)</sup>

---

**Ref:**

- For scholarly consensus on initiating fighting against everyone by default: [Bidaayat al-Mujtahid 2/144](https://shamela.ws/book/21739/390#p5), [Tabyeen al-Haqaa’iq 3/241](https://shamela.ws/book/23023/867#p1),
- For the Hikmah behind fighting and its constituents:  [Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah 15/158](https://archive.org/details/FPmfkmfk/mfk15/page/n157/mode/2up?view=theater) , [Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah 16/132](https://archive.org/details/FPmfkmfk/mfk16/page/n131/mode/2up?view=theater)