# End purpose of Islam

Tags: islamic-philosophy, end-times

We all know that Islam was brought into this world to bring peace and brotherhood in this world but on the other hand from Hadiths and other sources, we know that till the end of times, there will be war and chaos and there will be coming of Imam Mahdi and Prophet Isa and Dajjal as they will come at the end of times when there will be lots of battles and fights.

I see this as a contradiction because on the one hand, Islam was brought to bring order to life on Earth, and on the other side we see that till the end of time, there will be battles between people of different religions specifically Jews. This clearly shows that till the end of time, there will be existing non-Muslims and Islam will not be a global religion.

Isn't this similar to the fate of Jinns when they used to live on the planet and at the end of their time Allah SWT sent angels to fight them and eradicate them from the planet and then brought Humans on Earth? If that is true, then aren't we the same as Jinns and no better?

Answer (score 0):

Peace is a middle purpose and the end purpose is to at least one human know and meet Allah. Quran does not state the end purpose of Islam is peace. peace among believers is needed as a means to Allah be known. even Quran says Allah wanted to create life in the form that some humans be enemies of others:

[image]

> Said He, Get you down, each of you an enemy to each In the earth a
> sojourn shall be yours, and enjoyment for a time[(24)](https://quran.inoor.ir/fa/ayah/7/24/?language=4)

And this verse says peace with all is not purpose of Islam:

[image]

> Muhammad is God's messenger while those who are with him should be
> strict with disbelievers, merciful among themselves. [(29)](https://quran.inoor.ir/fa/ayah/48/29/?language=4)

[image]

> God is the One Who created seven heavens, and the same [number of
> planets] which are like the earth. The Command prevails among them so
> you (all) may know that God is Capable of everything. God comprises
> everything in knowledge! [(12)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/65/12/?language=4)

[image]

> Everyman, you are toiling constantly for your Lord, and you will meet
> Him! [(6)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/84/6/?language=4)

The purpose of Islam is not to eliminate all non-Muslims from the earth at the end of time. The Quran clearly states that humans are free to believe and practice any religion.

[image]

> We have guided him along the [right] path, whether he is thankful or
> thankless. [(3)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/76/3/?language=4)

[image]

> There should be no compulsion in religion. Normal behavior stands out
> clearly from error; so anyone who rejects the Arrogant ones and
> believes in God has grasped the Firmest Handle which will never break.
> God is Alert, Aware. [(256)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/2/256/?language=4)

Also, the war and chaos at the end of time are meant to prepare for the global governance of Imam Mahdi (a.s.), who will be the sole ruler of the world for many years before its end. Those wars are like necessary surgeries for the health of a body. Those wars and chaos are not the end of the world. All the earth will have one state, one governance, and one ruler. The wars mentioned are with the rulers and states who are his enemies and not with the non-muslim people.

About the Jinns, please note that they are living around us right now. And after the world ends and the entire universe is destroyed, Allah will create a completely new universe and a new generation of humans and jinn. This cycle will repeat forever and has repeated before us many times. [(ref)](https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa4175)

About your last question, each human can be better or worse than Jinns, and it all depends on the deeds of each human or jinn.

[image]

> O mankind, We have created you from a male and female, and set you up
> as nations and tribes so you may recognize [and cooperate with] one
> another. The noblest among you with God is that one of you who best
> performs his duty; God is Aware, Informed. [(13)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/49/13/?language=4)

Jinns, like humans, have free will and will experience either heaven or hell.

Comment: To quote "Peace is a middle purpose and the end purpose is to at least one human know and meet Allah.", can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: To quote "The purpose of Islam is not to eliminate all non-Muslims from the earth at the end of time", this means that until the end of times, there will be chaos and no brotherhood. If non-Muslims will be present even before the arrival of Imam Mahdi, there will be chaos and fights. Also, in another way, Islam prescribes the conquest of essentially every place to bring it under Islamic rule and I highly doubt that this will be a "peaceful" act.  And how do you think there will be global governance of Imam Mahdi, by peace? Imam Mahdi is one of the signals of end times.

Comment: All I am trying to say is that till the end of times, Islam will not be able to bring peace and brotherhood among people (not considering any creed) if we look in the context of my question. Please also check this question that I asked https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/what-is-the-reason-behind-gazwa-e-hind which says that for the expansion of Islam chaos is imminent.

Comment: When I mentioned the fate of Jinns, I meant that it is similar to ours. Jinns have free will too and so do humans. Jinns brought chaos and corruption to the world and so are humans doing the same.

Comment: To quote "This cycle will repeat forever and has repeated before us many times.", can you please share the reference for this as I am hearing this for the first time? Thanks!

Comment: @Ganit middle purpose for example you study to then have job so study is middle purpose. 
yes will be chaos until Imam Mahdi a.s. establish his government. his appearance starts with wars. yes it is not peaceful. it needs wars. I did not think it will be by peace. it will be by war. but war ends and all his enemies will defeat. and then peace starts and he governs for years. 
peace will be after wars when all enemies defeated.
chaos and corruption is in creation of both human and Jinn.

Comment: @Ganit for recreation I added a reference.

Comment: Oh ok! So Muslims will be/have to be in a state of war with non-muslims till Imam Mahdi comes and suddenly when he comes there will be global dominance of Islam. Is that right? In a nutshell, people of Islam or Islam as a whole will not be able to bring brotherhood and peace in this world until Mahdi comes. Ok! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Ganit not war with any non-muslim. not ant all of them have war with Muslims. for example mostly Christians have no war with Islam. the problem is mostly Jews. read [this verse](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/5/82/). war is with leaders and who want to eliminate Muslims. not those who have no problem with Muslims. Islam lets non-Muslims be free in religion. yes the global peace will be after Mahdi a.s. comes. but still some hypocrites exist who can not fight but have hate of Imam Mahdi a.s. and seek a situation to kill him but he will be protected by God based on end of

Comment: [this verse](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/17/33/). this verse is about Imam Hussain a.s. and Imam Mahdi a.s. who will revenge him and rulers who suppressed real Islam including corrupted Muslim rulers and kings. and dead rulers after prophet a.s. till now will become alive for revenges.